# DNS ODBC Driver configuration for SSH RDS

Tags: postgresql, ssh, odbc, rds

I´d like to know if it is possible to connect to my rds database from my local machine (windows) using windows odbc data source. My problem is that I use SSH and i don´t know how can I input the parameters in odbc data source. I need this type of connection because I want to access RDS via vba excel. My database is Postgresql.

Comment: How are you using ssh?  I didn't think RDS allowed for that.  Can you show us what you are doing on your non-Windows system which works?

Comment: I created a bastion on ec2 to ssh. I find an alternative way to connect to rds with ssh. Im using Putty to tunnel the connection to a specific port on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a publicly accessible database (not recommended by AWS) and your IP address is allowed, then the normal ODBC connection will work.

By the sound of your setup, you have a private database. In which case, your options are:

1. Use a different ODBC driver that supports tunnelling.

Devart (https://www.devart.com/odbc/postgresql/) and Cdata (https://cdn.cdata.com/help/FPG/odbc/RSBPostgresql_c_SSH.htm) both have ODBC drivers that support SSH tunnelling.

Neither are free.

2. Use a VPN and point your driver at localhost

Answer (score -1):

Indeed, you can use Devart ODBC Driver for PostgreSQL to access data in the specified environment. Please check additional information in the documentation: https://docs.devart.com/odbc/postgresql/ssh.htm